# I'm creating a custom directive and @Input() isn't binding the way I am intending

Tags: angular

StackBlitz - https://angular-hof8w9.stackblitz.io

Custom Directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appBorder]',
})
export class BorderDirective {
  @Input('appBorder') borderColor!: string;
  defaultColor: string = 'black';

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.applyBorder(this.borderColor || this.defaultColor);
  }

  applyBorder(color: string): void {
    console.log(this.borderColor); // Undefined
    this.el.nativeElement.style.border = `5px solid ${color}`;
  }
}
```

app.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { BorderDirective } from './border.directive';
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent, BorderDirective],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.html

```
<div [appBorder]="color" style="height: 100px"></div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  color: string = 'red';
}
```

The border of the div should be red but is being defaulted to black (specified in the directive) because the @Input() is undefined. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the property on your constructor, [it hasn't been initialized yet](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). Try using `ngOnInit()` instead.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ul2vp5?file=src/app/directive/border.directive.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as your input.

```
@Input() appBorder = 'black';
```

Comment: Still not working unfortunately.